# How to iterate over prefixes of an infinitely long string?

Tags: bash

I am running code which I will `foo`.  It takes two arguments, a string of 1s and 0s and an integer.  The strings are prefixes of the infinitely long string `110011001100110011...` in increasing length (in fact it won't ever be longer than 50).  For each prefix, the second argument should take the values from 1 up to the length of the prefix.

So I would like bash to run the following in a loop.

```
foo 1 1
foo 11 1
foo 11 2
foo 110 1
foo 110 2
foo 110 3
foo 1100 1
foo 1100 2
foo 1100 3
foo 1100 4
foo 11001 1
foo 11001 2
foo 11001 3
foo 11001 4
foo 11001 5
foo 110011 1
foo 110011 2
...
```

Is this possible?

I can make a doubly nested loop using something like:

```
for i in {1..10}; do for j in $(seq 1 $i); do foo $i $j; echo $i $j; done; done
```

But I don't know how to tackle the problem I described.

Comment: ''The strings are prefixes" - what is prefix for `110011001100110011` in your meaning?

Comment: There are no infinite strings. What is your termination criterion (longest prefix)?

Comment: @Jens It won't be longer than 50

Comment: I do not understand, so infinitely or no longer than 50? 50 elements or 50 chars? `run the following in a loop.` Can you list exactly all everything that you want to run? _How_ is the first number generated? How is the number in the third column generated?

Comment: @KamilCuk 50 characters.  so 1100 repeated 12.5 times.

Comment: `1100` repeated? The first element in the output you posted is `foo 1 1` not `foo 1100`. What should repeat and how?

Comment: @KamilCuk See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77132608/1473517 . That works

Comment: @EdMorton I am very happy with the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/77132608/1473517

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My take would be to construct the prefix character by character as we go, since there is a repeating 1100 pattern:

```
s=''
for i in $(seq 50); do
  case $((i % 4)) in
    (1|2) s="${s}1";;
    (*)   s="${s}0";;
  esac
  for j in $(seq $i); do
    echo foo $s $j
  done
done
```

This way you can easily adapt it to other regular 0/1 patterns of any length.
Bonus point for POSIXly portable scripting without bashisms. All you need is `seq`.

Comment: Downvoted because it gives bad example of using `seq` rather than initializing a counter and using a POSIXly correct and portable `while` loop.

Answer (score 3):

You may use this bash script for this with 2 loops:

```bash
arg="${1?need an argument}"

for ((p = 1; p <= ${#arg}; p++)); do
   for ((i = 1; i <= p; i++)); do
      echo "${arg:0:p} $i"
   done
done
```

Then run it as:

```bash
bash run.sh '110011'

1 1
11 1
11 2
110 1
110 2
110 3
1100 1
1100 2
1100 3
1100 4
11001 1
11001 2
11001 3
11001 4
11001 5
110011 1
110011 2
110011 3
110011 4
110011 5
110011 6
```

Comment: It could be misunderstanding on my part but I think this generates what OP wanted to generate minus starting `foo` part (which can be added easily)

Comment: It's just perfect. Thank you.